# Entire file is not read in C (EOF occurs unexpectedly)

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to print contents of a file with approximately 4000 characters.
Somehow the program records only the first 220 characters and terminates.

```
int main(void)
{
    char ch = ' ', file_name[25], payload[3904];
    FILE *fp;
    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
    gets(file_name);
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // read mode
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

    int gin = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)!=EOF))
    {
        printf("%d) %x \n",gin, ch);
        payload[gin++] = ch;
    }
    printf("Also, value of gin is %d --->", gin);
    getchar();

    //...rest of the code
}
```

Here the value of `gin` is 220.

Just to check, I modified the `while()` condition to run for the exact number of characters in the file:

```
{
 //...

 while (gin<3904)
 {
    if ((ch = fgetc(fp)) == EOF) res++;//ADDED THIS TO COUNT NUMBER OF EOF's
    printf("%d) %x \n",gin, ch);
    payload[gin++] = ch;
    //printf(" %x \n", payload[(gin - 1)]);

    if (gin % 100 == 0)     
    {
        printf("Also, value of res is %d --->", res); getchar();
        getchar();
    }
 }

 //...rest of the code
}
```

The value of gin reaches 3904, the value of res(no. of EOF's) is 3684, meaning that every character after the first 220 is being read as an EOF. The program starts reading `FF` after the first 220 character even though it is filled.

Comment: You want to make `c` an `int`. Have a look what type `fgetc()` returns.

Comment: `gets()` is danger...use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @sourav it says :"too few characters for fgets"

Comment: Oh, come on, please check the manual page.....

Comment: @alk the problem persists. I just changed type of c & payload[] to int

Comment: You are calling `fgetc` twice with the result of the first one being discarded. The result is that every second character is not being counted nor stored.

Comment: "while ((ch = fgetc(fp)!=EOF)" this line has a missing closing bracket. It won't compile. Please update your question with your actual compiling code. The location of the closing brackets does matter and may be one of your problems.

Comment: I corrected the mistake @alan and also added a few extra lines to see that all the characters after 220 are being read as EOF.
Is it possible that the problem is with fgetc?

Answer (score 4):

I think the code is fine, apart from the fact that you should change the `ch` to `int`.

[`fgetc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) returns

- If success, *"the character read as an unsigned char cast to an `int`"*
- In failure, *"`EOF` on end of file or error"*

So, first, you have to change the `ch` to `int`, as some return values from `fgetc()` may not *fit into* a `char`.

Now, in the second case, you're not checking the return value of `fgetc()` against `EOF` to detect any error .  You're  simply taking the return value and trying to store those values into the array. Actually, when the end of file is reached, there is nothing more to be read, and all the further reads on the same file pointer will return you error.

It is most likely that those values. after `220` in your case are *valid* , at all.

So, to the statement in your question,

> *(EOF occurs unexpectedly)*

is wrong. It occurs just fine, you're ignoring it and running into, well, *trouble*.

---

Note:

1. In your first snippet, you're doing two successive `fgetc()` calls, essentially discarding the result of the first one, and using the second one without any check.
2. Never use `gets()`. It suffers from buffer overflow issues. Always use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: I changed the data type of both ch and payload[], but the problem persists.
It prints the right values till 220, then "ffffffff"

Comment: @paneerchatpata there are only 220 valid chars in the file, beyond that, all the reads are error.

Comment: my file clearly contains a lot more than 220 characters. Is it possible that the error is because of use od fgetc?

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

```
uses fgets() rather than the obsolete gets()
removed the newline from the user input
uses the proper size_t rather than int for indexing
is consistently indented
has modification to the printf statements to display size_t rather than int
compiles cleanly (which surprises me as payload is set but never used)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch = ' ';
    char file_name[25];
    char payload[3904];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
    fgets(file_name, sizeof(file_name), stdin);

    // remove trailing newline
    char *newline = strstr(file_name, "\n" );
    if (newline )  *newline = '\0';

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // read mode
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

    size_t gin = 0;
    while ( ((ch = fgetc(fp)!=EOF)) && (sizeof(payload) > gin) )
    {
        printf("%ld) %x \n",gin, ch);
        payload[gin++] = ch;
    }

    printf("Also, value of gin is %ld --->", gin);
    getchar();

    //...rest of the code
    return(0);
}
```